French movie about 3 proofs of love, one of which is to kill someone
I'm trying to find out the name of a french movie, in which a guy falls in love with a young girl. She is not an average girl, and is a bit crazy (in a relaxed way), with dyed hair (I don't remember which color, perhaps blue or purple)
The plot then turns odd when she tells him that if they really love each other, they should pass three "tests" each.
I kind of remember that one of the "proofs" was to have sex with a person of their same sex (him with a man and her with a woman). I am not 100% sure of this one.
The one I do remember, and is part of the main plot is, that they have to kill one person each. I can't remember the other "proof" but it was trivial in comparison. 
It didn't matter who they killed, preferably a stranger, but things then got interesting.
Before getting to the spoilers, here are some other details I remember:

He knows her in a wedding of a common acquaintance / relative.  
She lives alone in an old, abandoned looking, big house.    
I believe she makes art, not sure if she makes photographs, paintings or
sculptures, I think at some point she makes a sculpture/model of his head.   
At some point, they are going to have sex, and since her hair is dyed, he asks her if her pubes is also dyed.

Spoilers from here on!

 He is so mad in love that he in fact considers the murder, so he goes finding someone who will not be missed. He finds a homeless guy in a park. He remembers that she also knows him, and she would notice if he goes missing, so is the perfect victim.
 He plans to kill him, but regrets, and instead of actually killing him, I believe (not sure) he pays him to disappear, move to another city, or something. He then goes to his girl to tell her that he fulfilled the promise, that he killed the hobo. Since the hobo was well known to both, and he is no longer there, she believes him.
 xxxxxx ULTRA BIG SPOILERS FROM HERE ON, REVEALING THE ENDING... YOU CAN STILL STOP READING! xxxxxxx
 He feels guilty for lying, but I don't remember if he tells her the truth, but then the girl tells him that actually she has also killed someone for him, and takes him to an old house, and then shows him that she have murdered someone (a woman), and had kept the rotting corpse there, waiting to be shown to him as her ultimate proof for her love towards him!

There are some details I don't remember exactly, (like when he tells the truth or when he lies but gets along with it), where do they met, etc. Besides, I missed the first 20 or so minutes of the film. But those are minor points. If you have watched the movie, you will definitively remember it for what I have said.
I watched it on TV and assume is quite recent, no more than 10-15 years old. I am almost completely sure it was French spoken, it definitely wasn't English spoken.
I hope someone can remember and tell me what movie it is!

Plot sounds so interesting, good luck! And if you really want to find this movie don't avoid spoilers ;)

According to the [help/on-topic], spoilers are allowed within the body of a question, just not the title. Please add all of the information you can, in order to help us help you.

but is there a spoiler tag so even if I put one, people have to hover over it to read it?

@DiegoDD Yes: write >! before the text. Were they punks, BTW?

@Walt, no, the girl has blue/purple hair, but not "punk" as in the style / subculture. The guy was average.

+1 for a very detailed question (& possible match posted).

At first I thought of Jeux d'enfants (AKA Love Me If You Dare), but it sounds like you're talking about Claude Chabrol's La demoiselle d'honneur (AKA The Bridesmaid) from 2004, though some of the details are a bit off. From IMDb (contains spoilers, of course, and the most important part is in italics):

In Lille, the hairdresser Christine has raised her son and two daughters alone. [...] Christine invites her son [Philippe] and daughters to meet her boyfriend, the wealthy Gérard Courtois that has just divorced and is selling his house. She gives her garden stone head of the goddess of flowers Flora that Philippe adores to Gérard that tells her that he has a business travel to Italy on the next day, but he disappears from Christine's life. In Sophie's wedding, Philippe meets her sexy bridesmaid and Jacky's cousin Stéphanie "Senta" Bellange and they have one night stand. Despite the odd behavior of the unstable and apparently imaginative Senta, Philippe immediately falls in love for her and suggests four weird things to prove their love: planting a tree; writing a poem; having homosexual intercourse; and killing a person. When a homeless beggar is found murdered in the harbor, Philippe decides to fantasize that he had murdered the man to prove his love to Senta. On the next morning, when he wakes up, Senta tells that she had murdered Gérard to please Philippe and describes her crime in details. Philippe decides to visit Gérard to find the truth about Senta. 

Here's the trailer:




YEAH! that is definitely the one! Now I see that I had some details wrong, but you managed to find it! thank you very much! I totally recommend it.
